# Strange NSOrderedSet Behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code which should properly set up a table view with calendar events:

```
...

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate and DataSource methods

- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    ...

    NSLog(@"TEST %d", self.user.calendarDays.count);
    NSLog(@"TEST %@", [self.user.calendarDays objectAtIndex:3]);
    return self.user.calendarDays.count;

    ...

}

...    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    }

    ...

    NSOrderedSet *calendarDays = self.user.calendarDays;
    NSLog(@"CalendarDays: [%@]", calendarDays);
    CalendarDay *calendarDay = [calendarDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"CalendarDay: [%@]", calendarDay);
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[calendarDay calendarEvents] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];

    ...

    return cell;
}

...
```

However the app crashes every time on the line `CalendarDay *calendarDay = [calendarDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`. The output (including NSLogs):

```
2013-11-25 13:05:34.731 Nobles[9176:60b] TEST 4
2013-11-25 13:05:34.734 Nobles[9176:60b] TEST <CalendarDay: 0x155a3960> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x155a2f50 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/CalendarDay/p26> ; data: <fault>)
2013-11-25 13:05:35.280 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDays: [Relationship 'calendarDays' on managed object (0x155616e0) <User: 0x155616e0> (entity: User; id: 0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1> ; data: {
    assemblySeat = "";
    calendarDays =     (
        "0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3>",
        "0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5>",
        "0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7>"
    );
    correctPIN = 1;
    cubby = 1;
    faculty = 0;
    homeSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae7d0 'homeSportEvents'>";
    lockerCombo = "";
    lockerNum = "";
    macLockerCombo = "3-29-35";
    macLockerNum = 133;
    menuBackground = 0;
    mySportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae820 'mySportEvents'>";
    name = Carlo;
    parent = 0;
    peopleID = 21894;
    pin = cabelli16;
    proPic = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 000100fa 00fa0000 fffe001f 4c454144 20546563 686e6f6c 6f676965 7320496e 632e2056 312e>;
    reservations = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae860 'reservations'>";
    resultSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8a0 'resultSportEvents'>";
    scheduleDays = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8e0 'scheduleDays'>";
    student = 1;
    unid = cabelli16;
}) with objects {(
    <CalendarDay: 0x1567ab70> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x155b1820 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A2>"
    );
    dateString = "11/16/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x15683c80> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15683940 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A4>"
    );
    dateString = "11/17/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x156842d0> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15684150 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A6>"
    );
    dateString = "11/18/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})
)}]
2013-11-25 13:05:48.933 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDay: [<CalendarDay: 0x1567ab70> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x155b1820 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A2>"
    );
    dateString = "11/16/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})]
2013-11-25 13:05:48.940 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDays: [Relationship 'calendarDays' on managed object (0x155616e0) <User: 0x155616e0> (entity: User; id: 0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1> ; data: {
    assemblySeat = "";
    calendarDays =     (
        "0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3>",
        "0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5>",
        "0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7>"
    );
    correctPIN = 1;
    cubby = 1;
    faculty = 0;
    homeSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae7d0 'homeSportEvents'>";
    lockerCombo = "";
    lockerNum = "";
    macLockerCombo = "3-29-35";
    macLockerNum = 133;
    menuBackground = 0;
    mySportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae820 'mySportEvents'>";
    name = Carlo;
    parent = 0;
    peopleID = 21894;
    pin = cabelli16;
    proPic = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 000100fa 00fa0000 fffe001f 4c454144 20546563 686e6f6c 6f676965 7320496e 632e2056 312e>;
    reservations = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae860 'reservations'>";
    resultSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8a0 'resultSportEvents'>";
    scheduleDays = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8e0 'scheduleDays'>";
    student = 1;
    unid = cabelli16;
}) with objects {(
    <CalendarDay: 0x1567ab70> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x155b1820 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A2>"
    );
    dateString = "11/16/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x15683c80> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15683940 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A4>"

    );
    dateString = "11/17/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x156842d0> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15684150 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A6>"
    );
    dateString = "11/18/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})
)}]
2013-11-25 13:05:50.116 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDay: [<CalendarDay: 0x15683c80> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15683940 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A4>"
    );
    dateString = "11/17/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})]
2013-11-25 13:05:50.122 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDays: [Relationship 'calendarDays' on managed object (0x155616e0) <User: 0x155616e0> (entity: User; id: 0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1> ; data: {
    assemblySeat = "";
    calendarDays =     (
        "0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3>",
        "0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5>",
        "0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7>"
    );
    correctPIN = 1;
    cubby = 1;
    faculty = 0;
    homeSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae7d0 'homeSportEvents'>";
    lockerCombo = "";
    lockerNum = "";
    macLockerCombo = "3-29-35";
    macLockerNum = 133;
    menuBackground = 0;
    mySportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae820 'mySportEvents'>";
    name = Carlo;
    parent = 0;
    peopleID = 21894;
    pin = cabelli16;
    proPic = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 000100fa 00fa0000 fffe001f 4c454144 20546563 686e6f6c 6f676965 7320496e 632e2056 312e>;
    reservations = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae860 'reservations'>";
    resultSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8a0 'resultSportEvents'>";
    scheduleDays = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8e0 'scheduleDays'>";
    student = 1;
    unid = cabelli16;
}) with objects {(
    <CalendarDay: 0x1567ab70> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x155b1820 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A2>"
    );
    dateString = "11/16/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x15683c80> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15683940 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A4>"
    );
    dateString = "11/17/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x156842d0> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15684150 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A6>"
    );
    dateString = "11/18/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})
)}]
2013-11-25 13:05:51.548 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDay: [<CalendarDay: 0x156842d0> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15684150 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A6>"
    );
    dateString = "11/18/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})]
2013-11-25 13:05:51.553 Nobles[9176:60b] CalendarDays: [Relationship 'calendarDays' on managed object (0x155616e0) <User: 0x155616e0> (entity: User; id: 0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1> ; data: {
    assemblySeat = "";
    calendarDays =     (
        "0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3>",
        "0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5>",
        "0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7>"
    );
    correctPIN = 1;
    cubby = 1;
    faculty = 0;
    homeSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae7d0 'homeSportEvents'>";
    lockerCombo = "";
    lockerNum = "";
    macLockerCombo = "3-29-35";
    macLockerNum = 133;
    menuBackground = 0;
    mySportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae820 'mySportEvents'>";
    name = Carlo;
    parent = 0;
    peopleID = 21894;
    pin = cabelli16;
    proPic = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 000100fa 00fa0000 fffe001f 4c454144 20546563 686e6f6c 6f676965 7320496e 632e2056 312e>;
    reservations = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae860 'reservations'>";
    resultSportEvents = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8a0 'resultSportEvents'>";
    scheduleDays = "<relationship fault: 0x155ae8e0 'scheduleDays'>";
    student = 1;
    unid = cabelli16;
}) with objects {(
    <CalendarDay: 0x1567ab70> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x1567ade0 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A3> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x155b1820 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A2>"
    );
    dateString = "11/16/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x15683c80> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15683d00 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A5> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15683940 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A4>"

    );
    dateString = "11/17/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
}),
    <CalendarDay: 0x156842d0> (entity: CalendarDay; id: 0x15684470 <x-coredata:///CalendarDay/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A7> ; data: {
    calendarEvents =     (
        "0x15684150 <x-coredata:///CalendarEvent/t2757F3FB-BC75-435C-B0A4-FDA936D3E91A6>"
    );
    dateString = "11/18/2013";
    user = "0x1554ad10 <x-coredata://FA2FBE99-00BF-4603-8479-9DAC1881AAC6/User/p1>";
})
)}]
2013-11-25 13:05:53.801 Nobles[9176:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSOrderedSetM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3099ae83 0x3acf76c7 0x3092ed87 0xd17fb 0x33251315 0x331f96cd 0x331f8ef1 0x3311f353 0x32da5943 0x32da1167 0x32da0ff9 0x32da0a0d 0x32da081f 0x3311768b 0x30965f69 0x309638f7 0x30963c43 0x308ce471 0x308ce253 0x356082eb 0x33183845 0xbff3d 0x3b1f0ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Why can the objectAtIndex:3 be retrived in the NSLog in the numberOfSections method but not in the cellForRow method?

**EDIT:**

I have no idea if this is related or not but a few days back (when my Calendar was still sort of working) I posted this question about something strange going on: [UITableView Search Causes Strange Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183013/uitableview-search-causes-strange-scrolling)

Comment: First thing - break up the crazy long nested line into half a dozen lines. Assign each level into a separate variable so you can debug the code.

Comment: @rmaddy Is that easier to read or would you like me to divide it further into variables?

Comment: Since you didn't do what I suggested, it isn't any better. Besides, the suggestion was for you, so you can debug the code by seeing the each of the intermediate results. And I was talking about the line in `cellForRow...` that is causing the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy I divided up the code a bit for the `cellForRow`. I also changed the output. Do you have any idea why in the `numberOfSections` the count is 4 and I can access the 3rd index but not in the `cellForRow`?

Comment: This is a lot of code to read through. Any chance you could cut it down to the essence in a few lines? As it stands, one could nearly get the impression that you are trying to get the community to debug your code for you :-) Instead, try to re-produce the issue in something like 10 lines and you got a great, answerable question. You may even end up answering it yourself if you go through that process :-)

Comment: @rmaddy My apologies for posting all of the code. I just asked a question where the person answering insisted they needed all my parsing code to see how the array was populated so I figured I'd just start there :). I cut it down to the only lines I really care about.

Comment: @cabellicar123 No need to apologize to me. I didn't suggest cutting it down. But it was a good suggestion. You usually only want to post relevant code. And sometimes you will be asked to add more if needed. If we all knew exactly what to post every time, we probably wouldn't need this site.